# Setup remote environment when using xdist

Tags: python, pytest

I'm currently working on a project involving tests to be run at a remote host (bash).
Unfortunately, the remote python interpreter does not respect the available site-packages (it's an embedded one: abaqus python (2.6)). Using the PYTHONPATH variable, however, works to specify local installations and makes additional packages available. Hence, on the remote machine I simply add a respective line to my .bashrc file.

Unfortunately, when distributing tests using *xdist* only a "bare" bash is invoked, without any profile specific rcs loaded. Thus, the tests fail with some import errors as argparse, which is required by pytest is not available.

Is there a way the setup a remote host before it starts executing any pytest code (which requires argparse)? In other words is there a way to add environment variables on the hosts before the pytest imports start?

I tried using fixtures with session scope and `autouse=True` which (of course) didn't work. Moreover I tried something like

```py
# in conftest.py
import sys    
def pytest_configure_node():
    sys.path.insert(1, "/somepath/")
    print sys.path
```

This looks like it is executed on the remote host but *sys.path* remains the hosts one and the argparse module still cannot be imported.

I start the tests using

```
py.test --tx ssh=user@server//python="abaqus613 python" -vs --dist=each --rsyncdir foo
```

This starts the right python interpreter (Python 2.6.2 for Abaqus 6.13-2), but fails with

```
ImportError: No module named argparse
```

Comment: What command are you using to run `xdist`?

Comment: what line are yout using to set PYTHONPATH in .bashrc when testing manually?

Comment: something like `export PYTHONPATH=/path/to/argparse/library`

Comment: Would something like adding: `--rsyncdir /local/path/to/argparse argparse` work? It should sync argparse to the remote directory. I'm not sure about how you can do this remotely without breaking stuff. When you say `bare bash`, what do you mean? Did you add the PYTHONPATH in the logged user's env? Can you do it system-wide using `/etc/environment` or `~/.profile`? I may try reproducing the error later.

Comment: Using `~/.profile` does not work and I don't have the rights to change `/etc/...`. With "bare" I mean it behaves similar to `env -i bash --noprofile --norc` but I'm not perfectly sure it is really equivalent. 
I didn't manage to get the _rsyndir_ working. It always raises `ValueError: arg ../argparse not relative to an rsync root`

Comment: Perhaps try adding a secure shell environment in `~/.ssh/environment`. See if it has any effect.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67524/discussion-between-jakob-and-reut-sharabani).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figured out a quite hackish but reasonably working way. It is possible to specify a series of commands in the python call, hence I source a script which setups the environment before calling abaqus python.

The setup script (*setup.sh*), located on the remote machine, looks like:

```
export PYTHONPATH=/path/to/libraries
```

and the complete call is now

```
py.test --tx ssh=user@server//python="source setup.sh;abaqus613 python" -vs --dist=each --rsyncdir foo
```

This way I get the necessary imports working in abaqus python.

Answer (score 0):

My plugin https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest-cloud should help you

it automatically rsyncs python virtual environment to the slaves, one requirement is that your virtualenv folder should be inside of the folder where test folder is

after rsync it also activates the virtual environment so all your dependencies are there properly